# Linux Mint 21 Terminal windows not showing as open in taskbar

Tags: linux-mint, taskbar, ubuntu-20.04

Since Mint's the last update to ubuntu 20.04, I have seeing issue with some windows showing up in the taskbar. Here is an example:
[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvOFv.png)
This issue also applies to folders that are open.
This is driving me crazy as I have tons of Terminals and Folders open in the background, but I can't see them.
I JUST re-installed Mint to try fixing this so it is still showing up. Is this supposed to be doing this? Is this some setting that I don't know about?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The following command solved the problem for me:

```
dconf reset -f /org/cinnamon/
```

I found the solution on the following page which helped me:
[mint-forum](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=2004336#p2004336)

It is also mentioned in the corresponding entry that all self-made settings are lost.